# Flutter pubspec.yaml: Publishable packages can't have 'path' dependencies

Tags: flutter, dart, pubspec

I made my own Flutter package 1 year ago and want to update it now. I find an error I didn't see before, so would like to get ideas how to solve it.

**Structure**
/
∟ pubspec.yaml (pubspec.yaml for my package)
∟ example (example APP that uses my package)
　　∟ pubspec.yaml (pubspec.yaml for this example APP)
　　∟ lib
　　　　∟ main.dart

**Problem**
I used to use this below, but now it shows a message: Publishable packages can't have 'path' dependencies. Try adding a 'publish_to: none' entry to mark the package as not for publishing or remove the path dependency.

```
my_package:
  path: ../
```

I would like to know how to load my_package (the latest unpublished version) from pubspec.yaml for this example APP while making sure I can publish this package to Pub.dev.

[image]

**Versions**
Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 12.1 21C52 darwin-arm, locale en-CN)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add `publish_to: none` to the `example/pubspec.yaml` file since that's the pubspec for the example not the actual package. The package can still be published.

If in doubt look at what other people are doing: this is the `flutter_bloc` package [`example/pubspec.yaml`](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/033c95260e8f638a32a1733cfd2575e2480e2cd3/packages/flutter_bloc/example/pubspec.yaml)

```yaml
name: example
description: A new Flutter project.
version: 1.0.0+1
publish_to: none

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.13.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_bloc:
    path: ../

dependency_overrides:
  bloc:
    path: ../../bloc
  flutter_bloc:
    path: ../

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Notice the `publish_to: none`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me - the error is still present